# Android, database, google maps

Tags: android

I want to store a set of regions in a database, each region corresponds to a position, the user must enter the name of the region, then the application will take him to the corresponding location. can any one please propose to me how can i implement this.

Comment: store it in your database with its corresponding latitude and longitude(coordinates)

Comment: this part is pretty clear for me, but how can i establish the link between google maps and my database and let the user define a region to be guided to.

Comment: you can use SQLite as your database, create method that require a region and return a coordinates then supply that coordinates to a mapview.